# Is there an RSS / notification to MS KB's?

Tags: rss, vendors

There seem to be many interesting KB relevant for us developers. For example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842/en-us

Is there any way to get these updates by rss / mail?

Comment: Personally, I don't have the motivation to read them until I actually encounter a problem that makes one of them relevant, in which case a Google search generally identifies the relevant article pretty well.

Comment: I want rss for two reasons:
- sometimes I'm already developing a complex workaround for a newly released KB. I want it "pushed" to me.
- not all KB are hotfix some just give me heads up on issues I may phase

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that as Robert says, you really want to find these only when you have the problem. Hotfixes are to bail you out until a well-tested fix is available via the Service Pack - we in Windows Serviceability issue many hotfixes, and it's just *not possible* for us to do the thorough, broad testing that we do for service packs and official releases, despite us doing our best to ensure that hotfixes still are good quality.

If Microsoft provided a RSS feed, people would install way more hotfixes than they should, and we don't want people to unintentionally break their own apps and not be able to find out which of the 30 hotfixes they installed is to blame.

Plus, even if a hotfix fixes a specific issue with an app, shipping hotfixes with your app is always trickier than saying "You must be running SP(n) or above"; you have to make sure you're installing the right version and arch of the fix, you have to try to code up "is this installed" routines that end up breaking if MS reissues the hotfix, you have to sign a contract with Microsoft, yadda yadda yadda...

Answer (score 0):

Here is such a list:

http://support.microsoft.com/selectindex/?target=rss

Text for the filter; so much for brevity.